# Use new subclass with already in use database in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

I'm trying to create a customized User class inheriting from django User. Problem is I already have some users in database which can not be deleted whatsoever and also I have another class (let's say reports) which have a foreignkey to User. My question is: Is there any way to create my new User class and keep the old data too? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need two different User Classes? or might an attribute e.g. a role for the user be enough. What are you aiming for?

Comment: @niklas I want my users to be able to store multiple emails. right now my alternative is using a many-to-one relationship where I have an ExtraEmails class and that class has a foreign key to user model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create related model that links back to `User`. This is a common approach if you have different types of users, but there are also other use cases.

```
class SpecialUserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    special_feature = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    etc.
```

What you also need to do is create this profile, when new user is added to `User`. You can do this with [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) signal.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_special_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    if created:
        SpecialUserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

You create profiles for existing user with a [command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) or write and run a temporary function that does that for existing users in `User`.

Now you can use ORM in the sense of `user.specialuserprofile.special_feature`.

This way you'll keep using `User` model as a base, it won't mess with build-in user related functionalities, won't have think about new and old users and you can use this new model for any additional information about users.

Comment: thanks. that's a brilliant approach and more or less what I am doing right now. But if I change user to SpecialUserProfile.user I have to do a lot of changing in my code. that's why I was wondering if there was a way to inherit the User model without losing it's data.

Comment: Yes, changing base `User` model later in the project is difficult. This is the most elegant solution. For this reason it is recommended to always create custom `User` model by subclassing [`AbstractUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) when starting new project. But we all make mistakes, or forget about that. I know I forgot at least two times.